# SQLException pg_get_serial_sequence NOT FOUND

Tags: java, postgresql, junit, h2

I am trying to do JUnit tests with H2, and my APP is configurated to work with PostgreSQL, and with ACL's Spring Boot.

So I have to add into the app the next two lines:

```
`mutableAclService.setClassIdentityQuery("select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('acl_class', 'id'))");
mutableAclService.setSidIdentityQuery("select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('acl_sid', 'id'))");`
```

to create the AclService.

I have in the application.properties the configuration (`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test_db;MODE=PostgreSQL`)

But it always returns me:

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback;
>   uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select
>   currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('acl_sid', 'id'))]; SQL state [90022];
>   error code [90022]; Function "PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL
>   statement: select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('acl_sid', 'id'))
>   [90022-197]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:
>   Function "PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement ...

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Have you verified that H2 supports Postgres system functions?

Comment: I did not found anything about if H2 is compatible with this function, so this ws why I am asking for.

Comment: h2 is not Postgres. The only way to get a database that works and behaves like Postgres is to use Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the

```
"select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('acl_class', 'id'))"
```

for a SQL standard query

```
"SELECT CURRVAL(SELECT SEQUENCE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'acl_class' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'id')"
```

it works!

Comment: It isn't standard, it is H2-specific. Such information can't be obtained using the standard syntax only.